# POST Jsonobject to jax-rs gives unsupported mediatype

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, post, jax-rs

I am able to post JSON as string to my service but face problem when I change POST content as `JSONObject` type:

Code at server side:

```
@POST
@Path("/post") 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setJson(JSONObject p){
    JSONObject obj = p;
    String x = obj.toString();;
    System.out.println(x);
    run(x);
    return Response.status(201).entity(x).build();
}
```

curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"follow_request_sent": false,"default_profile": false, "following": false}' http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/webresources/helloworld/post
```

error:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type)
```

P.s : this mode of accepting JSONObject works well with GET but creates problem with POST

Comment: How does this work for `GET`? What JSON library do you use? How?

Comment: Have a look at Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/, it would handle the deserialization to Thing, and then you can serialize it back to a string with a new genson instance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a custom class with JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Thing {

    private boolean follow_request_sent;
    private boolean default_profile;
    private boolean following;

    // Constructors, Getters, Setters, toString()
}
```

Then you can write your method like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setJson(Thing t) {
    System.out.println(t);
    return Response.status(201).entity(t).build();
}
```

**Note**

1. Don't use a path like `/post`. Use a collection resource like `/things`. `POST`ing to this collection resource would create a new `Thing`.
2. Add `location(URI)` to the building of the `Response`. This `URI` should be the URI of the newly created `Thing`: `/things/23`.

Comment: I dont want to use mapping because in some cases fields may disappear depending on POST request , I just want to take a complete JSONObject as  POST and use it. I should use URI for better performance thanks :)

Comment: You don't have to post a JSON string with all properties filled. If some properties are missing, the default values of the `Thing` class are used.

Comment: ohh never thought  that way , problem is I can only send JSON objects from client and i wanted to take them as JSONObject and convert them to string, so if i use above method then I will explicitly make a string out of all class elements